# How would I merge two dataframes using a "contains" condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two tables `df1`:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo |
| 2 | Bar |

and `df2`:

| description | category |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | cat1 |
| Barrista | cat2 |

I now want to merge the dfs based on the "description" column if the string in `df2` contains the string of `df1`.

Right now I could only make it work with exact matches but not for `contains` cases:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='description', how='left', suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
```

which returns

| id | description | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | cat1 |
| 2 | Bar |  |

but the desired output `df3` should look like:

| id | description | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | cat1 |
| 2 | Bar | cat2 |

Comment: Your code gives the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft a regex to extract the patterns in df1, then `merge`:

```
import re
s = df1['description'].sort_values(key=lambda s: s.str.len(), ascending=False)
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, s))
# 'Foo|Bar'

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='description',
                right_on=df2['description'].str.extract(fr'({regex})',
                                                        expand=False),
                how='left', suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
```

*NB. I am sorting the words of df1 by decreasing length to ensure that a longer match would be used in case of multiple matches.*

output:

```
  description  id description_1 description_2 category
0         Foo   1           Foo           Foo     cat1
1         Bar   2           Bar      Barrista     cat2
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandasql

```
df1.sql("select self.*,df2.category from self left join df2 on instr(df2.description,self.description)>0",df2=df2)
```

out

```
    id description category
0   1         Foo     cat1
1   2         Bar     cat2
```